# how to parse everything that comes after 'P' with java pattern matcher?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have some data items of the form:

```
blahblahblahP26
blahblahblahP82982
blahblahblahP0
blahblahblahP913
```

I know that the java pattern matcher is a bit different than normal regex.

What I'd like to do is just grab everything that comes after the P. No more, no less.

How to do that?

Comment: Can you have a `P` inside your `blahblahblah` or are `P` only before the last number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex. Try to use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

```
  String afterP= str.substring(str.indexOf('P')+1); 
         // Add 1 if don't want to include P
```

If `P` appear multiple time than you can use `lastIndexOf('P')`

Comment: You will have ot use `contains()` to first check if the String contains `P`. Else you will get an error (`indexOf` will return -1)

Comment: it always will contain `P` but the numbers afterwards are variable length, sometimes wil be short, sometimes long. is it ok?

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō - Ya.. In that case this answer is OK

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō, How long your number is? If it is too long than you can convert number `String` to  `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("P[0-9]+");
    Matcher m=p.matcher(inp);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(inp.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    }
```

Use this regex inside inp pass the String you want to parse. It work for variable integer followed by P

Answer (score 0):

I'd clear everything that's before your `P`. With this you also take care of possible `P` that are before the last one:

```
String afterP = str.replaceAll("^.*P", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have learned regex in other language , then [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) should be enough for you to learn about java regex . If you are new to regex , this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) is very detailed. 
And for your case this should work:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(P.*)"); // question mark is Reluctant quantifiers , it fetch sequence as short as possible. 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("blahblahblahP26");
    if(matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```